# Magento - Paypal Express Checkout's return url

Tags: paypal

does anyone knows the `Return URL` for Paypal Express Checkout of magento 1.6.0?

I know that for standard its 
https://www.yoursite.com/paypal/standard/success/

Thanks..

Comment: https://www.yoursite.com/paypal/express/return/

Comment: oh thanks.... how did yo find this out? I had been looking for it for a long time

Comment: also, what would be the IPN url?

Comment: see app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers and you will find all urls

Answer (score 2):

Based on Comments above, the URL is

```
http://yoursite.com/paypal/express/return
```

Additionally, all PayPal IPN URLs can be derived from the controller files in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers
```