# Paypal Express Checkout return URL customization

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, payment-methods, paypal-express

is it possible to customize the standard Paypal Eypress Checkout return URL https://www.yoursite.com/paypal/standard/success/ ?

If yes, then how?

We would love to use our own, standard success page. The store is running on Magento 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers and you will find all urls

So there you should be able to change this address as well.

This question got asked [here as well](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4678/magento-paypal-express-checkouts-return-url)

Comment: You can also check the folder Controller/Express of the same module, that contains the URL for the express method. (As of Magento 1.9.1)